# Bootstrap popver for element generated at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Problem statement

I need to add bootstrap popover  at runtime ,
i followed this  [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BcczZ/2/#) for example.

i have forked the above fiddle to customise as per my need

Link to [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhavansekar/BcczZ/276/)

i am trying to add new bootstrap popover on button click, Link is added successfully but pop over dosent work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="well">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="And                 here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover</a>

<a class="btn bad">Bad button</a>

</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var $popover = $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();

//first event handler for bad button
$('.bad').click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
});


$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target),
        isPopover = $(e.target).is('[data-toggle=popover]'),
       inPopover = $(e.target).closest('.popover').length > 0

//does absolutely nothing. Only wastes memory
$('.bad').click(function () { 
    console.log('clicked');
    return false;
    });

//hide only if clicked on button or inside popover
if (!isPopover && !inPopover) $popover.popover('hide');
});
```

Dependencies:
jquery 1.9.1
bootstrap-combined.min.css
bootstrap.min.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize the popover after adding.

```
   var $popover = $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/gfD6X/1/)